# Creating object from class with __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dllexport, declspec

```
//file.h
# define PartExport __declspec(dllexport)
namespace Part{

class PartExport MyClass : public data::anotherClass{
  MyClass();
  void read();
};
}
```

I want to access this function by doing this below. Visual studio suggests to do "Part::read();" and f12 to that function works.

```
//main.cpp
#include <file.h>

int main(){

   Part::read();
   return 0;
}
```

But when compiling it complains about syntax errors because it thinks that PartExport is the class name. How can I access this function or create an object of MyClass?

edit: I realized that all the syntax errors on the class comes from the #include . I dont know what that means

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @JørgenFogh 'read' is not a member of 'Part', 'read' identifier not found. And the syntax errors in my comment on the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `MyClass` is exported, hence you should write in your main :

```
Part::MyClass myClass;
myClass.read();
```

If you want to call your function as you actually do in your main, you should write in your `file.h` :

```
namespace Part{

  void PartExport read();

}
```

But in this case you will lose your class encapsulation.

---

Another thing : to create your dll you have to specify the `__declspec(dllexport)` to export the function in the library.

But when your are using it, you should not tell your executable that you want to export this function as it was already exported in your library.

I advise you to compile your dll defining this macro in your project : `PART_EXPORT_DLL`

Then write it like this in your `file.h`:

```
//file.h
#ifdef PART_EXPORT_DLL
#    define PartExport __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define PartExport __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
namespace Part{

    class PartExport MyClass : public data::anotherClass{
      MyClass();
      void read();
    };
}
```

And when you want to import it, be sure **not to** define `PART_EXPORT_DLL`

Comment: This gives me syntax errors on "class PartExport MyClass : public data::anotherClass{". Syntax error: ':', Syntax error: public, Syntax error: missing ';' before '{', Syntax error: missing ';' before ':'. And an error that says that MyClass uses an undefined class 'Part::PartExport'

Comment: That macro is already in there, sorry for leaving that out. All the compilation problems are there because of the #include <file.h> what could that mean?

Comment: When the pre-processor encounter an `#include "file.h"` instruction, you can consider that it makes a copy/paste of `file.h` in your actual file so he the compiler will have all the definitions it needs to compile your file. Then, if you include exports instructions whereas you want to import dll exported functions, you will have some trouble ...

Answer (score 1):

What you want to access is NOT a function, but a member-function.
As such you have to specify which class it is a member of.

And as you haven't declared it static which would have made it similiar to a function, you even have to instantiate one of your MyClass before you can access it. (A non-static function has a 'this'-pointer, without an instance of your class there would be no 'this')

The namespace 'Part' is just another wrapper around your class.

To Access something in a namespace you do something like this:

```
Part::somethinginmynamespace
```

To call a function in a namespace you do

```
Part::somefunction();
```

To access a static memberfunction you use

```
Part::SomeClass::SomeStaticFunction();
```

To access a non-static member function you do:

```
Part::Someclass myinstance;
myInstance.myFunction();
```

If you get errors on a define, and the compiler thinks it's a classname, then the define is undefined.
Maybe you put it in a comment, or the upper/lowercase is wrong.

Comment: I wanted to do like dkg said first. But since it wasnt working and visual studio suggested to go direct to the function I thought I could try that out. It is not recognizing MyClass as a class. It suggests "Part::PartExport" as the class in the dropdown meny from my Main

Comment: You shouldn't completely rely on IntelliSense, that is sometimes badly broken.